# Send up arrow `↑` character to iPhone with SMS using VBA and a CDO mail object

Tags: iphone, vba, utf-8, sms

I need to send an up arrow `↑` to an iPhone with SMS using VBA and a CDO mail object.

My attempts are as follows:

**Unicode:**

```
subj =  ChrW(8593) & " Up " & ChrW(8593)
```

**HTML:**

```
subj =  "&uarr; Up &uarr;"
```

Both of the above methods result in the iPhone receiving either a `? Up ?` for the Unicode or `&uarr; Up &uarr;` as a string literal.

Does anyone know the correct syntax for an up arrow `↑`?

Comment: You want to send [Oliver Queen](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0028557/?ref_=tt_cl_t1) by SMS?

Comment: Wouldn't that need a `StrConv` call?

Comment: lol; I would suppose that his quiver might get caught in the SMTP port so I'd settle for a &uarr; character.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - If the iPhone is translating HTML to rich text then I think the HTML would work but it doesn't. Also, the Unicode is being stripped at the server or through receiving SMS, not when I send it. I know you can send an iPhone message using emoticons, etc. but I do not know how they encode them. [edit] I'll try sending as strconv(.., vbunicode).

Comment: Sorry @Mat'sMug, `strconv(.., vbunicode)` makes a garbled mess of the subject and truncates the message body altogether (likely from hitting a 0x0 character).

Comment: Found a solution; see below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution:**

I was looking for some 'special character' syntax but the problem was not in the construction of the message. I needed to add `.BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"` to the CDO.Message  object and use the Unicode `Chrw(8593)` where I needed it.

```
Sub sendMSSG(sbj As String, mssg As String)
    Dim cdoMail As New CDO.Message
    On Error GoTo err_Report

    With cdoMail
        With .Configuration.Fields
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = cdoSendUsingPort '2
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "my.smtpserverserver.net"
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic  '1
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = sFROM
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = sFROMPWD
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 6
            .Update
        End With
        .BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"     '<~~ THIS WAS REQUIRED
        .Subject = sbj
        .From = sFROM
        .To = sPHONEMSSGNO
        .Bcc = vbNullString
        .Cc = vbNullString
        .TextBody = mssg
        .Send
    End With

    Exit Sub

err_Report:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Apparently, `.BodyPart.Charset` covers both the subject and the message body as I was able to use unicode in both.

---

<sub>Anyone planning to use this code for their own purposes needs to add the **Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 library** to their project via Tools, References.</sub>