# Excel VBA CDO Mail

Tags: vba, excel, cdo.message

I'm trying to send a mail with Microsoft Office Excel 2007 VBA code but I'm getting the error:

> Run-time error '-2147220973 (80040213)':
>
> Automation error

The code that I'm using is:

```
Dim cdomsg As Object

Set cdomsg = CreateObject("CDO.message")

With cdomsg.Configuration.Fields

  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smptserverport") = 25
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
  ' .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "excel.**********@gmail.com"
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "**********123"
  ' .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
  .Update

End With

With cdomsg

  .Subject = "Automated mail"
  .From = "excel.**********@gmail.com"
  .To = "**********@hitbts.com" ' https://temp-mail.org/
  .TextBody = "Automated mail"
  .AddAttachment ("*:\*****\***********\****************\***********\*****\*****.xlsm")
  .Send

End With

Set cdomsg = Nothing
```

I have tried other smpt servers, the server name and address that shows in the cmd when I type in [nslookup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461224), the computer's IP and another IP but I don't know what's the correct smpt server.

**Edit after answer:**

To anyone searching for this in the future, the code I used and worked is the following (taken from [this](https://youtu.be/cOhupIT0rNA) video):

```
Dim Mail As New Message
Dim Config As Configuration
Set Config = Mail.Configuration

Config(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
Config(cdoSMTPServer) = "smtp.gmail.com"
Config(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 25
Config(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic
Config(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = True
Config(cdoSendUserName) = "sender@gmail.com"
Config(cdoSendPassword) = "password123"
Config.Fields.Update

Mail.AddAttachment ("C:\path\file.ext")
Mail.To = "destination@gmail.com"
Mail.From = Config(cdoSendUserName)
Mail.Subject = "Email Subject"
Mail.HTMLBody = "<b>Email Body</b>"

Mail.Send
```

Make sure to change `"sender@gmail.com"`, `"password123"`, `"C:\path\file.ext"` and `"destination@gmail.com"` for the example to work and the subject and body to change the mail.

I also went to the top menu "Tools" on the VBA, option "References...", enabled "Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 Library" and pressed OK as shown in the video linked above.

[Direct link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) to enable the "Less Secure" option for GMail taken from [here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm).

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927471/send-up-arrow-%E2%86%91-character-to-iphone-with-sms-using-vba-and-a-cdo-mail-object) for good working CDO.Mail code.

Comment: I see an error in the following line:  `.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smptserverport") = 25`.
**smptserverport** should be **smtpserverport**

Comment: @Slaqr You're correct but that still didn't fixed the error.

Comment: @Jeeped That code didn't worked. I get the same error without the `On Error GoTo`.

Comment: As you're using Gmail; did you check whether enabling 'less secure apps' made a difference? [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en)

Comment: @Slaqr That fixed the issue and the mail was sent, thank you so much! If you can make it the [offial answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597/7393973) so it can be accepted.

Comment: The error certanly gives almost no help to solving it. I tried so many different ways and it was always the same. Now I finally know how to send the mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using Gmail; did you check whether enabling 'less secure apps' made a difference? 
[Support.google.com Reference](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Huhlo,

I have been using a similar code to the one discussed here. It had been very reliable in many different operation systems and Office/ Excel versions. It had also worked reliably in different countries in different internet connections and providers. On a recent trip to Malta, it failed to work on the two different computers I had with me, which had different systems and Office/ Excel versions. I tried different internet connections and providers, without success.
I cured the problem, so I am sharing the solution in case it may help anyone passing here in the future.

In brief,  the solution was to change the  `smptserverport") = 25` to `smptserverport") = 465`
( I note in passing that in previous similar codings of mine, (using both as Sending provider my gmail.com Email address and also my German Telekom , t-online.de , Email address ) that the coding worked with either 25 or 465. ( I had been using 25 in preference to 465, simply because  I had seen that used more often in similar codings ) )

Here is the full implantation of my solution, which works well for me.

I have changed my signature line of my procedure from this

```
Sub PetrasDailyProWay1_COM_Way()
```

so that it now takes in,  as value thereof,  the “smptserverport” number

```
Sub PetrasDailyProWay1_COM_Way(ByVal SmptySvrPrt)
```

Any `Call` of the routine, which I had, such as this `Call` line I had

```
     Application.Run Macro:="'" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm'" & "!ProAktuelleMacrosMtsch.PetrasDailyProWay1_COM_Way"
```

is now modified to pass the value of 25, thus:

```
     Application.Run Macro:="'" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm'" & "!ProAktuelleMacrosMtsch.PetrasDailyProWay1_COM_Way" , arg1:="25"
```

( The above code line runs the procedure,  `Sub PetrasDailyProWay1_COM_Way( )`  , which,  in my case,  is in another workbook to that in which the `Call` line is in . ( The workbook, "NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm" ,  is automatically opened if it is not already open,  by that code line ) )

I now have added, towards the end of my routine, `Sub PetrasDailyProWay1_COM_Way( )` ,   error handling which schedules a re run of that routine,  using the 465,  if the  initial run,  using 25 ,  fails.  ( This particular solution has the additional advantage that I get automatically a second try,  in the cases where,  in the original coding,  it had previously, occasionally,  did not work at the first attempt )

This was my previous end of my coding:

```
Rem 3 Do it
   .send
   MsgBox Prompt:="Done"
 End With ' CreateObject("CDO.Message") (Rem 1 Library End =======#
End Sub
```

Here is the now modified version:

```
Rem 3 Do it initially attempt with  25  ,  then in Malta as well maybe with  465
  On Error GoTo Malta                                                                             ' Intended to catch a possible predicted error in the next line when running the routine in Malta, or/ and an error in the second attempt at a code run                                                                            ' if the next line errors, then I scheduule the routine to run again with  "smtpserverport") = 465
   .send
  On Error GoTo 0
   MsgBox Prompt:="Done (with " & SmptySvrPrt & ")"                                               ' This will typically give either  "Done (with 25)"  or else  "Done (with 465)"  if the routine worked
 End With ' CreateObject("CDO.Message") (Rem 1 Library End =======#
Exit Sub                                                                                          ' Normal routine end for no error exceptional errected situation
Malta:                                                                                                ' Intended to catch a predicted error when running the routine in Malta, or/ and an error in the second attempt at a code run
    If SmptySvrPrt = "465" Then MsgBox Prompt:="Also did not work with  465  , Oh Poo!": Exit Sub ' case error with attempt with  465
 Application.OnTime Now(), "'" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm'" & "!'ProAktuelleMacrosMtsch.PetrasDailyProWay1_COM_Way ""465""'"
' On Error GoTo -1: On Error GoTo 0                                                               ' I do not need this as the  End Sub  will effectively bring down the errection state
End Sub
```

The syntax I am using in the `Application.OnTime` code line was quite tricky to figure out. ( It is more complicated than I need , but I wanted to keep the format consistent with that used in my `Call` code lines).

I could not figure out how to do that last bit of the `Application.OnTime`  code line with the argument somehow in `( )` brackets. I also could not figure out how to do that code line using named arguments, which I personally prefer. I did manage to do it with named arguments, if I called a procedure that took no arguments. But in the case of a procedure taking arguments, as is the case with the new modified code here, I could not find any syntax that worked. So if anyone can enlighten me on how to do that line in a working syntax, in a form similar to  this pseudo form, ( that does not work) ,  then I would be very interested.

```
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Now(), Procedure:="'" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "NeuProAktuelleMakros.xlsm'" & "!'ProAktuelleMacrosMtsch.PetrasDailyProWay1_COM_Way, arg1:=""465""'"
```

The use of 465 in place of 25 has been mentioned before , as have using one or the other. I have yet to see any explanation of what this “smptserverport” or other parameters really are, at least , in any form understandable to me. If anyone has any clear explanation, it would be an interesting addition here , in my opinion. ( Links to any existing explanations are no use to me, as I think I have seen them all . …. … I expect it may be one of those things that no one ever got around to documenting clearly, and in the meantime no one can remember what it is all about )

ThunkUs : - )
Alan