# Trying to create personalized emails with multiple attachments

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

Updated per suggestions from Jeeped:

I am looking for a method of creating a set of emails fitting the following parameters:

- each email will be personalized to the recipient and based off a template letter set by my supervisor.
- There will be a greeting line with their name and title, along with the names of the departments they oversee.
- each email will have a set of documents specific to that recipient.
- they should be saved to file for final inspection before they are sent.
- column 5 that is not referenced in the code below is the column containing the department name.

The closest I have come is the following code:

```vb
Sub send_template_w/attachments()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim o As Outlook.Application
    Set o = New Outlook.Application

    Dim omail As Outlook.Mailitem
    Set omail =.Createitem(olMailitem)

    Dim I As Long

    For i=2 To Range(“a100”).End(xlUp).Row

        With omail

            .Body = “Dear “ & Cells(i,1).Value
            .To = Cells(i,2).Value
            .CC = Cells(i,3).Value
            .Subject = Cells(i,4).Values
            .Attachments.Add Cells(i,6)
            .Attachments.Add Cells(i,7)
            .SaveAs Environ("HOMEPATH") &; "\My Documents\" & Cells(i,2).Value

        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

So far, this code will generate and save an email but what I want to do is use a present email template for these emails--either by adding the greeting at the beginning and department name into the body of the the email to be sent out. Can this be done through a word or Outlook document and if so, how?

Comment: Yes there is a way. There is some decent CDO mail code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927471/send-up-arrow-%e2%86%91-character-to-iphone-with-sms-using-vba-and-a-cdo-mail-object). Get started and come back if you have a **specific** coding question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a model of the mail. "Save As" to an .oft file. For example MyTemplate.oft

Instead of

```
Set omail =.Createitem(olMailitem)
```

there is

```
Set omail = o.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\MyTemplate.oft").
```

To add the entries from the Excel sheet you could include unique placeholders in the body of the template then `Replace` with Excel values.